# Deprecated REST API - android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, deprecated

I have created an android app to login using facebook, create events on facebook, create events on facebook. I think I have used a deprecated API but I thought I used the latest API - graph api. In my code some words in code are cut off like: AsyncFacebookRunner, Facebook, getAccessToken, setAccessToken, isSessionValid etc.

My functions were working fine with the old API, but yesterday my boss checked my code and asked me to do the entire app using a non - deprecated API.

I have done all coding without knowing that the API was deprecated.

I am really confused, what needs to be changed in order to convert the program to work with the latest API, should I change those keywords that are shown to be cut off, or is there any other way?

Any comments are welcome, I am really confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an upgrade guide:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/

It provides a high level of what's changed from 2.0 to 3.0. You can use that to help map your migration. For example, instead of using the Facebook object you now have to work with the Session object.

There are also sample apps available with the new SDK that can guide you with various parts of the integration, so take a look at those as well.